# While Installing Datatable Class not Found

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, composer-php, yajra-datatable

I ran into problem after running composer update

When i am trying to install laravel tables by `composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"~8.0"` 
i am having following error

```
Class 'Yajra\DataTables\DatatablesServiceProvider' not found
```

Removed it from, app.php. there is no serivce provider or alias.

I have tried both ways,  DataTables and Datatables with older versions.

Tried composer autodump, removing the vendor folder and installed again, it existes without installation, and i don't see any class used in app.php yet.

I am unable to install.

Comment: Have you searched in your entire project for the specific class name `DatatablesServiceProvider`? If the exception is thrown the reference has to exist somewhere, `composer` can't invent class names just to mess with you :). Also what version of Laravel are you using? Starting with 5.5 there's no need to register most Laravel packages because they have auto-discovery enabled (and this is the case with your package).

Comment: Maybe its cache issue. Can you try by clearing **bootstrap/cache** or running **php artisan cache:clear**

Comment: @GopalPanadi if it is yajra 8.0, I have already checked it is T instead of t.

Comment: @GopalPanadi yes it was a cache issue, but php artisan cache:clear, but it was also giving the error, so removed the cache manually, but it fixed

Comment: My answer was only about getting error even after removing the entire files and code. As I have faced such issue once and clearing the cache worked for me. Your answer might be the right one no doubt @Prafulla Kumar Sahu . I leave it to the questioner.

Comment: Great @DamanMokha. 1000 likes for me. :D

Comment: @GopalPanadi You are 100% correct, 1000s likes for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Fixed By removing cache from bootstrap folder and installing it all again.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this with  Class `Yajra\DataTables\DatatablesServiceProvider` with Class `Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,` in app.php and test, I think it is `T` instead of `t` and in alias it is

```
'Datatables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
```

this is for yajra data table 8.0